# ping: http://google.com: Name or service not known on minimal centos on virtual box

Tags: centos7

Installed minimal centos on virtual box. Getting this error when ping google.com.

ping: http://google.com: Name or service not known

Comment: do you you have a network connection? do you have a DNS set? you you use a proxy? did you ping google.com or http://google.com (the latter is not a domain name...)

Comment: CentOS(minimal) is in virtual machine. Bridge network adapter is given. I didn't set anything.

Comment: ping does not accept an URL, it accepts a hostname. You are supposed to run `ping google.com`  , not `ping http://google.com/`

Answer (score 13):

First make sure you have your network adapter enabled in virtual box settings.

Your network interface which you use it for connecting to internet might not be active.

1. To check this,use "**sudo nmcli d**" command.
2. If it is disconnected,use "**sudo nmtui**"->Edit a connection,select your network interface and
   choose "Automatically connect" option(by pressing Space key) and
   select OK.
3. Do "sudo reboot now"  After logging in,do "ping
   www.google.com".

You should be able to connect now.